# jQuery animate not working for left attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to use jQuery animate to fly logos (`<img>` elements) into position from outside the screen. And once again, it is not working.

Here is my javascript (the relevant part is in the `fly()` method.)

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  logoFlyer.init();
});

var logoFlyer = {
  numberOfLogos : 0,

  init: function () {
    logoFlyer.numberOfLogos = $('.logo').length;
    logoFlyer.fly(1);
  },

  fly: function (index) {
    logo = "#logo_" + index;

    $(logo).delay(300).animate({'left':'0px'}, 300, function () {
      if (index < logoFlyer.numberOfLogos) {
        logoFlyer.fly(index + 1);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And here is my css

```
.logo {
  height: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  overflow:visible;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.logo img {
  height: 80px;
  left: 1500px;
  position:relative;
}
```

When I set the logos' `left` to 0, they are indeed where I want them to go. So the problem lies with jQuery animate

If someone can help me out here you might just save me from ditching jQuery altogether and switching to angular.js.

Comment: Would you consider using only CSS3 for the animations? I could help you with that but there wouldn't be any jquery.animate

Comment: Sure, if you can make the images fly in one by one

Comment: would you post your relative markup too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this code:

```
$(logo).delay(300).animate({'left':'0px'}, 300, function () {
  if (index < logoFlyer.numberOfLogos) {
    logoFlyer.fly(index + 1);
  }
});
```

The interesting part here is `$(logo)` which i assume treated something like `$('#logo_1') or $('#logo_2') etc.`. So now the point is only `position relative/absolute` elements are able to be animated.

So you can check if this element has the position relative/absolute.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. THank you!

Comment: You are welcome @MarcoPrins Glad this is been a help.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a solution, but this solution is without jQuery (only CSS3!)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class='logo'>
        --- Image 1 ---
    </li>
   <li class='logo'>
        --- Image 1 ---
   </li>
   <li class='logo'>
       --- Image 1 ---
   </li>
   <li class='logo'>
        --- Image 1 ---        
   </li>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo {
list-style: none;
text-align: center;

/** To the left by default **/
-webkit-transform: translate(-100%);
-moz-transform: translate(-100%);
-o-transform: translate(-100%);
-ms-transform: translate(-100%);
transform: translate(-100%);

/** Translate Animation --> 0.3s ease effect **/
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

 .logo.show {
-webkit-transform: translate(0%);
-moz-transform: translate(0%);
-o-transform: translate(0%);
-ms-transform: translate(0%);
 transform: translate(0%); 
 }
```

**JS**

```
var logoFlyer = {
numberOfLogos : 0,

init: function () {
    logoFlyer.numberOfLogos = $('.logo').length;
     setTimeout(function() {
        logoFlyer.fly(0);
    }, 300);
},

fly: function (index) {
    // No need to add indexes
    logo = $(".logo")[index];

    $(logo).addClass("show");
    setTimeout(function() {
        logoFlyer.fly(index + 1);
    }, 300);
  }
} 

$(function () {
    logoFlyer.init();
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FK3BP/1/)